# CodeIgniter using header() and session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am building a small CodeIgniter application and I seem to have hit a snag.

When I set my session and use a `header()` or `redirect()` it eats the session and refreshes it, leaving me with no data in the session other then the autogenerated stuff.

The only way I can see to preserve the session is to use the `view()` function to redirect after I process data in the backend.

Is there a workaround to this problem or am I just prohibited to use a redirect if I want to save data in the session variable?

P.s. It would seem this was not the solution after all. I can now get the session to print in the view but when leaving the page to go to another, the session is lost again... I am really at a loss here :/

Comment: Are you using the Codeigniter session library? It will persist until destroyed.

Comment: It is autoloaded. 
For reasons unknown to me it refreshes the session on every page redirect

Comment: Can you share some code so that I can see what might be happening? Are you redirecting before setting the userData?

Comment: I am using HybridAuth to connect Facebook an retrieve the info from there. 
This info is then put into an array which is sent to the session ($this->session->set_userdata(array)) 
I can see that the session is fine just before redirecting to the landing page, but when i redirect from there, it overwrites the session with a fresh one, wiping any session data i set.

Comment: Page is http://www.rhw.dk/madmm
When i log in with http://rhw.dk/madmm/index.php/welcome/login/Facebook 
i am redirected to the landing page rhw.dk/madmm where it shows the session. 
When i try to go to another page from there, it eats the session. 
fx http://rhw.dk/madmm/index.php/welcome/item

P.s. i print the session data on each page so i can see what i contains. 
I add a new item to the session on the landing page and on the /item page, just to see if that persists, which it oddly does... 

Really lost here

Comment: It would seem it is the length of the session array that is the problem. I can fit 7 elements into the array and it persists, otherwise it is wiped on the first page redirect... Odd as hell

Comment: Are you using cookie based or DB backed sessions?

Comment: I was having the exact same problem... Then I saw that the session->set_userdata() method will only take up to 4Kb of data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... And as always, it was a very stupid one.

I was using a BIT type column in my database for the first time, thinking it would be a 1 or 0, so i gave that column a standard value of 0.

As 0 is not an appropiate value for a BIT type, it was the cause of why it did not work in the session.

I changed the type to tinyint as that serves me just as well and now it all works, rainbows and lollipops everywhere.

Sorry to waste your time but thanks for the help never the less.